# How to specify a special character ina regular expression

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to know where the first occurance of an open paren `(` occurs in `agent_name_login`.

I tried this:

```
regexp_instr(agent_name_login, '(')
```

When I run this it interprets the '(' as an actual open paren, not the string that I want to compare it to.

How do I get it to treat it as the string I want to do the comparison with and not the open paren?

Can I use some other function within snowflake?

Comment: Escape it with a backslash

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to know where the first occurrence of an open paren occurs in agent_name_login.

The easiest way is to use [CHARINDEX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/charindex):

```
charindex('(', agent_name_login)
```

Alternatively escape it with double `\`

```
SELECT regexp_instr(agent_name_login, '\\(')
<=>
SELECT regexp_instr(agent_name_login, $$\($$)
```